# How to show results of a form upon submission

Tags: php, javascript, html

Using WordPress, so PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript what is the best method of populating the results of a form upon submission? I could have a form with ddl, radio buttons, etc.

```
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female

     <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What is the best way of populating the results i.e. "67% of users are Female" and "30% ride bikes" on the same page once the submit button is triggered?

Comment: I dont get the percentage part, how do you calculate that, does it submit to your database?

Comment: I guess that is part of my question. What would the best way of performing those calculations be?

Comment: I think calculating and displaying are two independent things. You can do the calculations and save the results in a database or you can save raw results and do calculations on each request. For the display, showing percentages and other relative data, consider using a framework to do the drawing for you: PHP: [PHP charts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/), Javascript: [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or for simple stuff like showing x% vs y% consider CSS, [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#progress).

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
script.php
----------
<html>
<body>
<form method=post action=script.php>
   your form here...
</form>

<? if($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]>0) {
     //form was submitted to script, so process form inputs here and display results...
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you flesh this out a bit, or perhaps provide links torelevant articles?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="phpfile.php" method="Post">
...form here
</form>
```

phpfile.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sex'])){
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
}//etc..
//To show the result, simply echo it:
echo $sex;
```

You'll need some sort of storage system to be able to calculate the amount of each.
So what you would need to do is write a simple query where the value of the field is male or female. Then you can easily calculate it.

Comment: will this work for separate posts? i.e. if I fill out the form on 1 post maybe 70% of people ride bikes, but lets say the other post only 40% ride bikes. Will this render results independant of other posts even though they use the same form and php file?

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is add the form results to the database, then find the total number of results for both categories, then calculate the percent female and the percent bike.

The form page:

```
<html>
   <?php
      if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == "values") {
          //connect to DB and select table
          $male = count( mysql_query("SELECT gender FROM Table WHERE gender='male'"));
          $female = count (mysql_query("SELECT gender FROM Table WHERE gender='female'"));
          $car = count (mysql_query("SELECT vehicle FROM Table WEHRE vehicle='car'"));
          $bike = count (mysql_query("SELECT vehicle FROM Table WEHRE vehicle='bike'"));
          $totalResults = $male + $female;
          $totalVehicles = $car + $bike;

          $percentFemale = 100 * ($female / $totalResults);
          $percentFemale = number_format($percentFemale, 0);

          $percentBike = 100 * ($bike / $totalVehicals);
          $percentBike = number_format($totalBike, 0);

          echo "<p>" . $percentFemale . "% of users are female. </p>";
          echo "<p>" . $percentBike . "% of users use bikes. </p>";
      } else { ?>
         <form action="formProcessor.php" method="POST"><!-- You could also use GET -->
           <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
           <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female

           <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
     <?php } ?>
</html>
```

The formProcessor.php Page:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["sex"]) && isset($_POST['vehicle'])) { 
     //Connect to MySQL DB and select table here
     $sex = $_POST['sex'];
     $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table(sex, vehicle) VALUES($sex, $vehicle)"); //You may also want to add an id column, but...
     //Close mysql connection
     header("Location: /form.php?status=values");
     die();
   } else {
     die("There was an error in your submission.");
   }
?>
```

I think this answers your question, you've got a way to find the percent of female users and users on bikes. If you need that to be dynamic and show only the greater amount (or show both or something) just add a comment. This also assumes you are not using PDO, if you are, I can adjust the code. I just wrote the code, so I don't know for sure if it works, but here you go!

Comment: I appreciate the detail in your answer. I am still curious, will this code be unique depending on different posts? For instance, on post 1 60% ride bikes, on post 2 perhaps only 20% ride bikes. So is this code independent of other posts? Also, I'm not sure if I am using PDO, at least I have not enabled it myself